# fabricjs Interactive Drawing Do I need to reset the event system after drawing first shape?

Tags: fabricjs

Using Fabric.js to draw interactive shapes, I cannot edit the shapes unless i create more than one shape.

A demo to clearly show the issue is here http://jsfiddle.net/pingcrosby/brZ2N/

```
  Click the box tool and draw 3 boxes NOT overlapping and try selecting them.
  Click the arrow (selection) tool - now selecting the box does not work as expected.

    (once you click enough and it works..everything from then on works as expected)

    Now try a 3 boxes and select the bounding group
    Now suddenly selecting all works as expected.
```

Do I need to reset the internal event system after drawing an initial shape?

Comment: I can't draw a box there. Drawing circles, then selecting them with arrow tool seems to work as expected.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply (appreciated). Circles seem to work for me too - but why can you not draw a box. Is it a code issue or JsFiddle.  I was trying to drag/draw the box/circle out and have it instantly editable when your over a drag handle node.  I have a feeling I am off with the box offsets as the cursor is never over the drag handles during initial creation and sizing.  I believe this is a crucial issue.  If your willing i could send you my entire code example for you to see?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

4 years late, but I'm trying out Fabric and fixed @PingCrosby's fiddle.

I called `shape.setCoords()` when committing the shape on mouse up, this will set `object.oCoords`, otherwise it stays at the small initial rect instead if the resized one.
https://jsbin.com/rujete/edit?html,js,output

This is listed as one of the [Fabric gotchas](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Fabric-gotchas).
I've also updated https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/FAQ